Error during build: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when running ./gradlew assembleDebug
I am new to react-native I am trying to generate an apk for testing using the command ./gradlew assembleDebug
but I get an error knowing ./gradlew clean executes successfully!
./gradlew assembleDebug

Configure project :expo

Using expo modules

expo-asset (11.0.1)
expo-constants (17.0.3)
expo-file-system (18.0.6)
expo-font (13.0.2)
expo-keep-awake (14.0.1)
expo-modules-core (2.1.2)


Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.6.0
Gradle: 8.10.2


Task :react-native-reanimated:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema
C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native\codegen\lib\generators\modules\GenerateModuleJniCpp.js:439
.map(property =>
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-
Node.js v22.11.0

Task :react-native-reanimated:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Try clearing the build cache and node modules:
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Downgrade to react-native-reanimated to version2.17.0:
npm install react-native-reanimated@2.17.0

If the above suggestions don’t work, then you’ll have to include the versions of react-native and react-native-reanimated you’re using in your question. The error suggests a potential version mismatch between both packages. Hope this helps!
EDIT
Alternatively, try installing react-native-reanimated 3.6.1 instead:
npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
npm install react-native-reanimated@3.6.1

Then clean and rebuild:
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug


I have already tried to clear the build cache and node modules, but the problem is still present.
here are the versions I use
"react": 18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.3","react-native-reanimated": "3.15.3"

react-native-reanimated@2.17.0 is not compatible with react nation version i use
